# How to get distinct parent_sku count for the below dataset?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Need your help to extract distinct Parent_sku count from the below data set.

Condition: If one child of a parent_sku has "High" sales_tag then that parent_sku count should be excluded from "Low" sales_tag.

P.S. Sales_tag column is based on child_sku column.

Thank you for your help.

[Dateset_&_Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWbcH.png)

```
create temp table pb_sku_high as 
(
Select brand
,sales_tag
,count(distinct child_sku) as child_sku_count
,count(distinct parent_sku) as parent_sku_count
from pb_sku_base
Where sales_tag = 'High'
group by 1,2
);

drop table if exists pb_sku_low;

create temp table pb_sku_low as 
(
Select brand
,sales_tag
,count(distinct child_sku) as child_sku_count
,(select count(distinct parent_sku) from pb_sku_base 
        where parent_sku not in 
                           (
                            select parent_sku from pb_asins_base where sales_tag = 'High' group by 1
                           )
    ) as parent_sku_count 
from pb_asins_base
Where sales_tag = 'High'
group by 1,2
);

Select * from pb_sku_high
union all
select * from pb_sku_low;
```

Comment: Images can't be copied or searched. Please reserve them for things that *can't* be represented as text, like charts and graphs.  Code and data samples should be posted as text.  Also, what have you tried and what was the result?

Comment: should Parent_sku count for _low_ would be 4?

Comment: Parent_sku count for low would be 2 and high would be 3.

Comment: by counting its 4 not 2

Comment: "Low" would only count P4 and P5, because P1 and P2 have both "Low" and "High", and by the OP's noted condition, if a "High" tag exists, then don't count that parent in the total "Low" count

Comment: @nurul, it would be useful if you include some example of the effort that you've made yourself, so that others can help you understand what needs to be amended to get your desired result - rather than specifically just expecting someone to create the query for you

Comment: Yes by counting its 4 but we need to exclude P1 and P2 as they have one child with sales_tag "high"

Comment: @Craig, I've added the query that I've used.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow nurul, please have a tour on [ask] and [mcve]. it would be difficult for anyone to try to help you if the question is unclear.

Comment: Adding those strange queries does not easily construct your original dataset in the image. If you already have the _high_ and _low_ recordsets, why didn't you just join on the SKU instead of trying to post-process the result of a union query like this? Just stsick to the source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The presented schema is non-conducive to this type of query, however we can normalise the structure to extract a *parent* and the *child* rows based on the `Child_sku` value.

Then we can *LEFT JOIN* the *parent* to the *child* row to record the count.

> **NOTE:**
> This specific query will not likely return the correct counts if there are more than 1 single child for each parent, it is not clear from the instructions how that should be treated though, so it mnight give you what you need.

```
SELECT parent.Brand, CASE WHEN parent.Sales_Tag = 'High' OR child.Sales_Tag = 'High' THEN 'High' ELSE 'Low' END as Sales_Tag, COUNT(*) as P_SKU_Count
FROM Product parent
LEFT JOIN Product child ON parent.Brand = child.Brand AND parent.Parent_sku = child.parent_sku AND parent.Child_Sku <> child.Child_Sku
WHERE parent.Child_sku LIKE '%_C1'
GROUP BY parent.Brand, CASE WHEN parent.Sales_Tag = 'High' OR child.Sales_Tag = 'High' THEN 'High' ELSE 'Low' END
```

| Brand | Sales_Tag | P_SKU_Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Nike | High | 3 |
| Nike | Low | 2 |

You could also avoid the `CASE` in the `GROUP BY` statement and return the two counts in-line:

```
SELECT parent.Brand
     , SUM(CASE WHEN parent.Sales_Tag = 'High' OR child.Sales_Tag = 'High' THEN 1 END) as High
     , SUM(CASE WHEN parent.Sales_Tag = 'High' OR child.Sales_Tag = 'High' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as Low
FROM Product parent
LEFT JOIN Product child ON parent.Brand = child.Brand AND parent.Parent_sku = child.parent_sku AND parent.Child_Sku <> child.Child_Sku
WHERE parent.Child_sku LIKE '%_C1'
GROUP BY parent.Brand;
```

| Brand | High | Low |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Nike | 3 | 2 |

There is a DB Fiddle here to test with: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/s2hDvn8EU3QXcdwKqobhdc/0